# firebase android studio, firebase database subarray manipulation

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that is supposed to add a Room (custom object) to my database:
It's java - android studio.

```
public void addRoom(Room room) {
    this.addRoomToList(room);
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() + "/rooms");

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>)dataSnapshot.getValue();

            if (data == null){
                data = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            data.add(room.getHashMapFromRoom());
            // Save the updated subarray to Firebase
            dbRef.setValue(data);

            dbRef.removeEventListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            dbRef.removeEventListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

The function takes a room argument, retrieves the current array of rooms adds the new room to the array and the array to the database.
But, it will not work, the first time it's okay and will upload and update successfully, but when called a second time it will erase the room (because data is null from the database and it will create a new array).   How do I fix it?

Note: I also checked the parent of this rooms argument, meaning a higher hierarchy in the database, and I was able to read it and get a hashmap, but the specific array of rooms did not appear there.
Also, I did check and I have read/write permissions in the rules section in the database.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON data at `/users/$uid/rooms` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 1):

Well after hours of debugging, I figured it must be related to the fact that I do calls to this function one right after the other, so the array didn't have the time to update in the database. I wrote this, I know it's not ideal at all but it works...

here is the updated function:

```
    public void addDevice(Device device, int room_idx){
    this.devices.add(device);

    Thread addDevice = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            // Path: " + room_idx + "/devices"
            final boolean[] roomExistsInIdx = {false};
            while (!roomExistsInIdx[0]){
                DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("rooms");
                dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        ArrayList<Object> rooms = (ArrayList<Object>)snapshot.getValue();
                        int size;
                        if(rooms == null){
                            size = 0;
                        }
                        else{
                            size = rooms.size();
                        }
                        if (size - 1 >= room_idx){
                            if (device.getType() == Device.TYPES.AIR_CONDITIONER){
                                dbRef.child(room_idx + "/devices/" + device.getName()).setValue((AirConditioner)device);
                            }
                            else if(device.getType() == Device.TYPES.LIGHTS){

                            }
                            else if (device.getType() == Device.TYPES.TV){

                            }
                            roomExistsInIdx[0] = true;
                            dbRef.removeEventListener(this);
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Log.d("cancel", "cancel");
                        return;
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
    addDevice.start();
}
```